# How many pounds of frozen strawberries in a Strawberry blonde?

Tags: all-grain, secondary-fermentation, fruit

I'm brewing a 5 gallon all-grain strawberry blonde ale. I'd like to leave it for two weeks in primary, then rack on top of frozen strawberries in secondary. Would anyone have an estimate of how many pounds I could use for a nice, subtle flavor that doesn't overpower?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good starting point for fruit additions in 1lb/gl. Strawberries are pretty subtle, though.  I added 7.5lb to 5gl of blonde this summer, and the flavor was easily noticable without being overpowering.

Answer (score 3):

I made a Strawberry Saison last Summer and the 1lb/per gallon was a nice subtle flavor, but I think I may raise the to 1.5 pounds next time.

Also, I used frozen strawberries which I gently crushed.  Let them thaw a bit at the bottom of the secondary and then racked on top of them.  The beer was able to use all of the fruit this way.